# How we can read and write to same ObservableObject in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am making a `ObservableObject` class and then I am using it for reading and writing value in all app. when I am using my `ObservableObject` in my StateObject and ObservedObject, they are not the same data, but they are making a different variable in memory, how we can make `StateObject` and `ObservedObject` working on a same data?

For example my ObservableObject class has a variable called `stringOfText`, which as default has `No Data!` then I make a StateObject variable and start reading default value of `stringOfText`, then I change the default value of stringOfText and it does not show the update in my `ObservedObject`! what I am doing wrong?

```
class TextModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var stringOfText: String = "No Data!"
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var readStringOfTextView = TextModel()

    var body: some View {
        TextView()

        Text(readStringOfTextView.stringOfText)
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
    }
}

struct TextView: View {
    @StateObject var textModel = TextModel()

    var body: some View {
        Text(textModel.stringOfText)
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)

        Button(action: {
            textModel.stringOfText = "Hello, world!"

        }) {
            Text("update string of Text")
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how we can make StateObject and ObservedObject working on a same data?

You can make it via shared instance, in example:

```
class TextModel: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = TextModel()     // << here !!

    @Published var stringOfText: String = "No Data!"
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var readStringOfTextView = TextModel.shared  // << here !!

// ... other code
}

struct TextView: View {
    @StateObject var textModel = TextModel.shared // << here !!

// ... other code
}
```

Comment: thanks, I just changed @ StateObject inside TextView to @ ObservedObject and it worked. also I did changed @ ObservedObject to @ StateObject in ContentView, and also worked, It seems it works whatever they are! we can change both of them to @ StateObject and it would work or both to @ ObservedObject, and also it would work! So let me Ask you, what is the point of @ ObservedObject or @ StateObject, because they are working the same result for me. If you think this is deferent Topic let me know please

Comment: `@StateObject` must be used like `@State` and `@ObservedObject` is to be used like `@Binding` for best memory management.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the `TextModel` to the child view (use the **same** instance in both views):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var readStringOfTextView = TextModel()

    var body: some View {
        TextView(textModel: readStringOfTextView) // pass here

        Text(readStringOfTextView.stringOfText)
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
    }
}

struct TextView: View {
    @ObservedObject var textModel: TextModel // declare only

    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, I know this way of coding, the TextView is "source of truth" it should not be observe any thing! but the Text inside of ContentView should be carful about changing value of TextView and it must be observing! how we can do that? you used this code "TextView(textModel: readStringOfTextView)" that is not I want, It should be TextView()

Comment: @Omid I think you misunderstood the answer to your previous question. *It should be TextView()* - I disagree. Also your TextView isn't the *source of truth*. It only provides a way to manipulate data. Try focusing on what you want to achieve and not on what tool you need to use.

Comment: It is possible that I misunderstood, that is why I need to ask and learn, All I want is read and write at same TextModel, with this limitation that TextView is the source

Comment: @Omid But it shouldn't be. Is there any particular reason why do you want it this way?

Comment: I am just learning SwiftUI and I got this Question, I know it may be stupid or funny but I like to know, let me ask my question in this way: We have TextModel, ok? the default value is "No Data!", ok? How we can update default value of stringOfText in TextModel for later usage?

Comment: @Omid I believe my answer *answers* your question. You can edit the `stringOfText` in the `TextView` and then use it in `ContentView` anyway you want (eg. pass to other subviews).