# How to create a NavigationManager that would change tab within view models?

Tags: mvvm, swiftui, combine

I have a NavigationManager to handle changing SwiftUI tab bar selection.

It work if it is set as a `@EnvironmentObject` in my SwiftUI views, but not when the NavigationManager is called as a service in my view models. The thing is that I would like to use a simpler solution than passing around `@EnvironmentObject var navigationManager` around and pass them inside view model initializer as I have a lot of them and I am looking for a cleaner approach.

How can I use my NavigationManager to change tabs from inside my view models without passing it in init()?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

  @StateObject var navigationManager = NavigationManager()

  var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $navigationManager.selection) {
      AccountView()
        .tabItem {
          Text("Account")
          Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle") }
        .tag(NavigationItem.account)

      SettingsView()
          .tabItem {
            Text("Settings")
            Image(systemName: "gear") }
          .tag(NavigationItem.settings)
          .environmentObject(navigationManager)
    }
  }
}
```

The navigation manager that I would like to use within view models.

```
class NavigationManager: ObservableObject {

  @Published var selection: NavigationItem = .account
}

enum NavigationItem {
  case account
  case settings
}
```

My AccountViewModel and Settings View Model:

```
class AccountViewModel: ObservableObject {

  let navigationManager = NavigationManager()
}

struct AccountView: View {

  @StateObject var viewModel = AccountViewModel()

  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 16) {
    Text("AccountView")
        .font(.title3)

      Button(action: {
        viewModel.navigationManager.selection = .settings
      }) {
        Text("Go to Settings tab")
          .font(.headline)
      }
      .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
    }
  }
}


class SettingsViewModel: ObservableObject {

  let navigationManager = NavigationManager()
}

struct SettingsView: View {

  @EnvironmentObject var navigationManager: NavigationManager

  @StateObject var viewModel = SettingsViewModel()

  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 16) {
    Text("SettingsView")
        .font(.title3)

      Button(action: {
        navigationManager.selection = .account
      }) {
        Text("Go to Account tab")
          .font(.headline)
      }
      .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Make `NavigationManager` to have shared instance and use it from everywhere needed directly. Here is useful example https://stackoverflow.com/a/64580356/12299030.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to successfully inject my navigationManager as a shared dependency using a property wrapper and change its `selection` variable using Combine.

So I have created a protocol to wrap `NavigationManager` to a property wrapper @Injection and make its value a CurrentValueSubject

```
import Combine

final class NavigationManager: NavigationManagerProtocol, ObservableObject {

  var selection = CurrentValueSubject<NavigationItem, Never>(.settings)
}

protocol NavigationManagerProtocol {
  var selection: CurrentValueSubject<NavigationItem, Never> { get set }
}
```

This is the @Injection property wrapper to pass my instance of `NavigationManager` between .swift files.

```
@propertyWrapper
struct Injection<T> {

  private let keyPath: WritableKeyPath<InjectedDependency, T>

  var wrappedValue: T {
    get { InjectedDependency[keyPath] }
    set { InjectedDependency[keyPath] = newValue }
  }

  init(_ keyPath: WritableKeyPath<InjectedDependency, T>) {
    self.keyPath = keyPath
  }
}

protocol InjectedKeyProtocol {
  associatedtype Value
  static var currentValue: Self.Value { get set }
}

struct InjectedDependency {

  private static var current = InjectedDependency()

  static subscript<K>(key: K.Type) -> K.Value where K: InjectedKeyProtocol {
    get { key.currentValue }
    set { key.currentValue = newValue }
  }

  static subscript<T>(_ keyPath: WritableKeyPath<InjectedDependency, T>) -> T {
    get { current[keyPath: keyPath] }
    set { current[keyPath: keyPath] = newValue }
  }
}

extension InjectedDependency {

  var navigationManager: NavigationManagerProtocol {
    get { Self[NavigationManagerKey.self] }
    set { Self[NavigationManagerKey.self] = newValue }
  }
}

private struct NavigationManagerKey: InjectedKeyProtocol {
  static var currentValue: NavigationManagerProtocol = NavigationManager()
}
```

With this in place, I can pass my `NavigationManager` between my view models and send new value using Combine on button tap:

```
class AccountViewModel: ObservableObject {

  @Injection(\.navigationManager) var navigationManager
}

struct AccountView: View {

  var viewModel = AccountViewModel()

  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 16) {
    Text("AccountView")
        .font(.title3)

      Button(action: {
        viewModel.navigationManager.selection.send(.settings)
      }) {
        Text("Go to Settings tab")
          .font(.headline)
      }
      .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
    }
  }
}


class SettingsViewModel: ObservableObject {

  @Injection(\.navigationManager) var navigationManager
}

struct SettingsView: View {

  @StateObject var viewModel = SettingsViewModel()

  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 16) {
    Text("SettingsView")
        .font(.title3)

      Button(action: {
        viewModel.navigationManager.selection.send(.account)
      }) {
        Text("Go to Account tab")
          .font(.headline)
      }
      .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
    }
  }
}
```

To wrap things up, I inject `NavigationManager` in my ContentView and use the `.onReceive(_:action:)` modifier to keep track of the newly selected tab from anywhere in code.

```
struct ContentView: View {

  @Injection(\.navigationManager) var navigationManager

  @State var selection: NavigationItem = .account

  var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $selection) {
      AccountView()
        .tabItem {
          Text("Account")
          Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle") }
        .tag(NavigationItem.account)

      SettingsView()
          .tabItem {
            Text("Settings")
            Image(systemName: "gear") }
          .tag(NavigationItem.settings)
    }
    .onReceive(navigationManager.selection) { newValue in
      selection = newValue
    }
  }
}
```